How do you import musical symbol fonts into geometry nodes string to curve?
I want to animate music notation. There are several music notation fonts available: Bravura
Petrucci, Leiland, etc. But when I open these fonts in blender, I do not see any music symbols. 

This is because the characters in the font to represent musical notation are not at the alpha-numeric character mappings in the font.
To enter non-alphanumeric characters in Blender:

Find and open a character selector program (usually a built-in OS tool or at least an official desktop app).
Pick your musical notation font. The character selector may not support arbitrary files, so the font may need to be installed on your system first.
Find the musical notation symbols you need in the font’s full Unicode table.
Exact functionality depends on your character selector and OS, but you should be able to pretty easily copy-paste them into Blender.

Note: The characters may show up incorrectly in the node text entry field when you paste them, as Blender is not using the music notation font for its UI; only the rendered text. The text curves visible in the 3D Viewport should show up correctly.

You could also use "Replace String" nodes to replace readable characters with the notes.

Works 100%! Thank you LabCat
